# Избежать двоеточия

Tags: wordpress, vue.js, api

После получения данных путь до необходимых выглядит так:

```
{{list._links.wp:featuremedia[0].href}}
```

Но, Vue.js не понимает "**:**".

Как это можно исправить?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Покажите как Вы получаете данные.

Comment: `{{list.title.rendered}}` работает. Вот таким дивом `<div v-for="list in lists" v-bind:key="list.id">` Ошибка `Unexpected token :`

Comment: ок, `list._links.wp` допустим содержит в себе какие-то данные, зачем Вы здесь делаете это: `:featuremedia[0].href`? Если Вы хотите просто вывести `ЗНАЧЕНИЕ : ЗНАЧЕНИЕ`, то это делается так: `{{list._links.wp}}:{{featuremedia[0].href}}` или так: `{{\`${list._links.wp}:${featuremedia[0].href}\`}}`

Comment: Мне нужно достать href от туда. Выше картинку повесил.

Comment: тогда так: `{{ list._links["wp:featuremedia"][0].href }}`

Comment: `"TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined"`

Comment: Vue при создании виртуального DOM обрабатывает list, который Вы ещё не успели получить, из-за чего и эта ошибка. Можете поставить простое условие типа `{{ (list && list._links) ? list._links["wp:featuremedia"][0].href : "" }}`

Comment: К сожалению, условие не помогло( `Vue при создании виртуального DOM обрабатывает list, который Вы ещё не успели получить, из-за чего и эта ошибка.`- это странно title то он выводит

Answer (score 0):

В дополнение к вышеописанным комментариям...
Попробуйте так:

```js
const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      lists: [{
        title: 'title 1'
      }, {
        title: 'title 2'
      }]
    }
  },
  methods: {
    getHref(list) {
      return (list && list.hasOwnProperty('wp:featuremedia')) ? list['wp:featuremedia'][0].href : 'Loading...';
    }
  },
  created() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.lists = this.lists.map((el) => {
        return {
          ...el,
          'wp:featuremedia': [{
            href: 'link 1'
          }, {
            href: 'link 2'
          }, {
            href: 'link 3'
          }]
        }
      });
    }, 2000)
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <ul>
    <li v-for="list in lists">
      <h3>{{list.title}}</h3>
      <p>First link: {{ getHref(list) }}</p>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Здесь используется имитация загрузки через `setTimeout`. По умолчанию у нас `lists` не имеет свойства "`wp:featuremedia`", мы подгружаем его, а затем, с помощью метода `getHref` (который получает на вход один из элементов `lists`) получаем значение ссылки (если условие `list && list.hasOwnProperty('wp:featuremedia')` соблюдается). В противном случае пишем "*Loading...*".